# i get this error when trying to kill pulseaudio

Tags: bash, sound

```
$ pulseaudio -k

E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process
```

Is there any other way?

I tried the pavucontrol fix but it didn't work.

Comment: Please add output of `ps aux | grep [p]ulseaudio` to your question.

Comment: You've not told us what Ubuntu product & release you're using, are you sure you're using a system using `pulseaudio` and not a release/flavor that uses `pipewire` ?  Starting with details of what Ubuntu product & release you're using allow us to better understand & help you.